# Show Cross Site Collection's page in Sharepoint dialog box

Tags: cross-site

I have 2 web application and I am trying to open 1 site collection's application page in dialog box from the another site collection. It works fine in IE but in firefox I am getting following error

"Load denied by X-Frame-Options: 'site page url' does not permit cross-origin framing."

and in chrome I am getting follolwing error

"about:blank:1 Refused to display 'site page url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Please help in solve this issue
Thanks